# Spring Security - Can't Login After Clicking Logout

Tags: spring-security

I've added Spring Security to my application.  I am able to login fine but after I click logout, I'm then unable to login again.

Here is my applicationContext-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.html">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html*" filters="none"/>  
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1"
                default-target-url="/search.html"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    <concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>  
</http>

<!--
Usernames/Passwords are
    rod/koala
-->
<authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    <user-service>
        <user name="rod" password="a564de63c2d0da68cf47586ee05984d7" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
 </user-service>
```

Here is my login form:

```
<form method="post" action="j_spring_security_check">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="j_username">Username:</label></td>
            <td>
             <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" size="20" maxlength="50"
             <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                value="<%= session.getAttribute(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY) %>"
             </c:if>/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="j_password">Password:</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" size="20" maxlength="50"/>
            </td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me"/> Remember me on this computer.
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="button-submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And my logout link points to:`/j_spring_security_logout`

UPDATE:  (10.30.2009 09:44 EDT)

Some additional info, I enabled DEBUG level logging and can now see this in my console:

```
09:42:14 DEBUG [http-8080-1] (AbstractProcessingFilter.java:412) - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentLoginException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded
```

It would seem that this line from my applicationContext-security.xml has something to do with it:

```
<concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
```

I'm not sure why even if I've logged out that it thinks I've exceeded the max num of sessions.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

-aj

Comment: It would be great if whoever down voted this question could add a comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I just solved it.  ;)

This listener was missing from my web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I have similar issue, it is saying class not found in my console.. I am using Spring - 4 and `spring-security-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar`