# Why could a Spring3 Security login work only exactly once until the server is restarted?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Everything works like a charm the first time I login after deployment of my Spring security app. But after the first logout, I can't login again until the service is restarted! Also it seems as if the login was successful, as I can see the users data being loaded in the hibernate sql-log.

Here the relevant code fragments:
applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" security="none" pattern="/bookmark/add" />

<http auto-config="true"
      use-expressions="true"
      access-denied-page="/user/login"
      disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

    <form-login
            default-target-url="/dashboard"
            login-page="/user/login"
            login-processing-url="/user/doLogin"
            authentication-failure-url="/user/login/error"
            username-parameter="email"
            password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/user/logout"
            logout-url="/user/doLogout"
            invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="true" />

    <remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="myfancysalt" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/user/login">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" hash="sha-256">
            <salt-source system-wide="myfancysalt" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

<beans:bean id="rememberMeFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="loginUserDetailsService"/>
    <beans:property name="key" value="myfancysalt"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="key" value="myfancysalt"/>
</beans:bean>
```

LoginController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Principal principal) {
    if (principal != null) { // If user is already logged in, redirect him
        return "redirect:/dashboard";
    }
    return "user/login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"login/error", "/user/doLogin"})
public ModelAndView processLogin(Principal principal) {
    if (principal != null) { // If user is already logged in, redirect him
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dashboard", null);
    }
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("error", true);

    return new ModelAndView("user/login", map);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "logout")
public ModelAndView logout() {
    return new ModelAndView("user/logout");
}
```

The necessary filter in web.xml is present.

Any help is very much appreciated!

**### EDIT ###**:

The problem lied in the concurrent session limitation. After I removed the following part from the applicationcontext-security.xml, everything works fine. Can someone tell me what's wrong with it? (I just copy/pasted it from some howto).

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/user/login">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>
```

Comment: Only to isolate the problem: what happen if you remove the "Remember Me" functionality?

Comment: Could you also post relevant code for `loginUserDetailsService` ?

Comment: Removing "Remember Me" didn't change anything

Comment: Why do you make redirection by hand at your LoginController at login method()? Doesn't Spring Security do it?

Comment: @kamaci I just tried that, seems Spring Security doesn't. Without that redirect in the login method, I could visit the login page although I was logged in.

Comment: I know this is a 2011 post but for future searchers like me, aparently you forgot to add a listener at your web.xml as follows:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647855/spring-security-cant-login-after-clicking-logout
 I'm having a similar issue and I will test when I get home.
 Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do:

```
principal == null
```

before you logout.

Comment: Did you mean "principal = null"? I am not sure how checking for a logged in user before logging him out anyway could prevent him from being logged in again.

And if you meant "principal = null" - I just tried that, doesn't seem to do anything.